Evaluating triple sum
So recently I came across this question
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}  \frac{mn(3m+p)}{(4^m4^n4^p)(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
The first thing I tried was to evaluate first
$$\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}  \frac{mn(3m+p)}{(4^m4^n4^p)(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
=$$\frac{mn(3m+1)}{(4^m4^n4)(m+n)(m+1)(1+n)}+\frac{mn(3m+2)}{(4^m4^n4^2)(m+n)(m+2)(2+n)}....$$
but obviously I can see that this is not the right approach, and I am stuck
EDIT: also curious to know what the answer would be if the summations varied from 0 to infinity.

Could I know where you got this question from? I'm fairly sure the answer is $4.\overline{185}$

Normally my suggestion would be to swap the indices around and see what works (in your case Tonelli's theorem applies since every term is positive), but this is very symmetrical and ugly. How did you derive the closed form for summing over $p$? Mathematica spits out an answer in terms of the Lerch transcendent, a generalization of the Hurwitz zeta function and polylogarithms. Trying individual values of $m$ and $n$ produces algebraic combinations of rational numbers and logarithms.

@Igor this question was given by my professor, so I'm not sure about the exact source. May I ask how you got that answer?

@teadawg1337 I'm sorry if my question is very basic, but how do you justify swapping the indices?

@Vaibhav All of the terms are nonnegative, so Tonelli's theorem says that swapping indices is OK.

What is happening with the $m=n=p=0$ term? Wouldn't that term be $0/0$?

I just put it in WolframAlpha and put the limit of the sum to be 10, 15, 20, 25, etc, see this for example link and I can see the numbers of .185's is growing. Again I could be wrong, it's just a guess.

Is there a way to make use of the symmetry given? how would swapping indices be helpful?

A truly amazing question, which can be solved by closely observing the symmetry in the denominator- this means the variables can be swapped around without any harm.
Consider $$S:=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{mn(3m+p)}{(4^m4^n4^p)(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
The variables m, n and p can be permuted in 6 different ways
$$ (m,n,p), (m,p,n), (n,m,p),(n,p,m), (p,n,m) ,(p,m,n)    $$
consider these arrangements in the numerator of the given sum:
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{mn(3m+p)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)} & \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{mp(3m+n)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)}\\
&\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{nm(3n+p)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)} & \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{np(3n+m)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)}\\
&\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{pm(3p+n)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)} & \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{pn(3p+m)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)}
\end{align*}
now add all the numerators, which gives
$$ mn(3m+3n+2p)+np(3n+3p+2m)+pm(3p+3m+2n) $$
on further simplification this becomes
$$3(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)$$
and finally
$$6S = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{3(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)}$$
from here it can be solved with ease, as it becomes an infinite geometric progression, so I'll leave it to you from here:
$$6S = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{4^{m+n+p}}$$

You're right, we can exploit the cyclic symmetry of the expression and add all those to exploit the known formula for an infinite geometric progression
Note considering the sum begins from 1,
$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}  \frac{mn(3m+p)}{(4^m4^n4^p)(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}  \frac{mn(3m+p)}{(4^{m+n+p})(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
We can consider the partial sums
$$S_K=\sum_{m=1}^{K}\sum_{n=1}^{K}\sum_{p=1}^{K}  \frac{mn(3m+p)}{(4^{m+n+p})(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
$$S_K=\sum_{m=1}^{K}\sum_{n=1}^{K}\sum_{p=1}^{K}  \frac{mp(3m+n)}{(4^{m+n+p})(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
$$S_K=\sum_{m=1}^{K}\sum_{n=1}^{K}\sum_{p=1}^{K}  \frac{mn(3n+p)}{(4^{m+n+p})(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
A few more cyclic combinations and we add all those (a total of 6) combinations as follows,
$$6S_K=3\sum_{m=1}^{K}\sum_{n=1}^{K}\sum_{p=1}^{K}  \frac{1}{(4^{m+n+p})}$$
By the use of this,
$$S_K=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{K}\frac{1}{4^m}\right)^3$$
$$S\underset{\underset{{K\to \infty}}\lim}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^m}\right)^3$$
$$\boxed{S=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=\frac{1}{54}}$$

Edit (suggested from comments):
$$S=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}  \frac{mn(3m+p)}{(4^m4^n4^p)(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^k}\right)^3=\frac{32}{27}$$

Edit : Do note, I still do not have a concrete justification(yet) as to why this works for this specific case,
$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}  \frac{mn(3m+p)}{(4^m4^n4^p)(m+n)(m+p)(p+n)}$$
If we put $m=n=p=k$ (say), we get
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{k^2(3k+k)}{(4^k4^k4^k)(k+k)(k+k)(k+k)}$$
Which eventually becomes,
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^k}\right)^3$$
$$\boxed{S=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=\frac{1}{54}}$$

how does swapping the m's p's and n's not make a difference to the sum? I know it's because of the symmetry, but logically how?

@Vaibhav If i had to explain it in simple terms, its like you have two baskets B1 and B2 with some numbers of objects, you wanted whats the total number of objects combined, so does it matter if you add items of B2 first and then B1 or the other way round...
If you want a formal/better understanding, see this and this

that got things cleared,thanks

This method makes sense, but numerical computations show the sum in @Vaibhav's question to be equal to $\frac{113}{27}$; in other words, the zeroeth term in each sum is necessary and this method misses an additive factor of $3$. I don't immediately see why.

@teadawg1337 are you sure about 59/27?

@AmrutAyan I've dug much deeper, and if you're asking whether I'm confident about the accuracy of the numerical computations, then the answer is yes AND no. For some reason, Mathematica produces $4.\overline{185}$, whereas Sage produces $1.\overline{185}$ when separating the summand into two sums and adding them together. I'm inclined to believe the latter as the extra $3$ makes no sense.

@teadawg1337 so that would just be a correction of $$S\underset{\underset{{K\to \infty}}\lim}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^m}\right)^3$$
$$\boxed{S=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^3=\frac{32}{27}}$$

The main (first) method is fine, but I don’t see how the “clean solution by putting $m = n = p = k$” is valid.  Superficially, the same technique would let you argue $\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-(m+n)}(m-n)^2$ $= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-2k}(k-k)^2$ $= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty 0$ $= 0$ — but this is clearly wrong.  So it at least needs some non-trivial justification.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine i have not given a rigorous explaining to why m=n=p=k works, it was just an intuition that worked for this specific case only, call it a trick perhaps.

@AmrutAyan: A “trick” usually means a surprising but still valid argument.  A heuristic or intuition usually suggests the argument gives correct or near-correct answers in a good range of “typical” cases.  As far as I can see, the technique you use here only gives the right answer by coincidence, or at least for reasons very special to this particular example (more specific than just the symmetry or the simple form, as my example shows).  So it seems a bit misleading to present it without at least a clear caveat.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine agreed, i should remove it until i find a concrete justification for it... or till it fits a particular class of symmetry (if there exists any such classification)

Re the edit: does starting from 0 make sense?  Doesn't that involve 0/0?  Or are you deciding that term can be evaluated in some manner?

I originally posted this as an abridged comment under Amrut Ayan's answer. However, I'm expanding it into a full answer so it's more visible to everyone and because the question was edited to ask about summing from $0$ as a hypothetical. There was initially some confusion because the question was first posed as
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{mn(3m+p)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(m+p)},$$
which has a problem that was pointed out above by mathperson314 and Teepeemm: the term at $m=n=p=0$ is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$. When $m=n=p$ in general, the summand becomes $4^{-3m-1/2}$ (substitute $m$ with your preferred variable of the three). One might assume that this generalizes to the zeroeth terms as well and gives no issues (I initially did as well but somehow made an error in my previous code since I cannot reproduce the result), but consider the discrete limit
$$\lim_{(m,\,n,\,p)\underset{\mathbb{N}_0}{\to}(0,\,0,\,0)}\frac{mn(3m+p)}{4^{m+n+p}(m+n)(n+p)(m+p)}.$$
As stated above, taking the path $m=n=p$ gives a value of $1/2$; however, letting $m=0$ and $n=p$ gives a result of $0$. Hence, the limit does not exist, and we can conclude that summing from $0$ is impossible in the conventional sense. There are still ways to assign a value, such as not considering the triple sum as a single unit and performing each sum in succession, in which case the value is $113/27$. This would only be undefined if the summand is also undefined for any of $m$, $n$, or $p$, but not any combination thereof.
